# Can I use MD5+suffix for custom length of Unique ID?

Tags: php, hash, md5, uuid

I want to use it for data name, such as

```
// Get the file
$file = open('abc.txt');

// Get MD5 Hash value from the file content
// It should be 32 length and Append 2 more(suffix)
$name = MD5_from_file($file) + 'AZ';

// Rename the file as $name
rename($file, $name)

// Then, the file name like this: 9E107D9D372BB6826BD81D3542A419D6AZ.txt
```

Comment: [PHP: uniqid($file)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: or you can hash (md5 or sha1) the timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even simpler. Use sha1_file() instead of md5(). You really dont need a suffix, the hash value sha1 is designed to be unique and dependent on a concrete file. The likelyhood of two files having the same hash value is really minimal and as close to 0 as on will get.

```
<?php
$newName = sha1_file('abc.txt');
rename($file, $newName);
?>
```

Length of sha1() will be 40 chars.